# Advanced or not so advanced pre_get_posts query

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts, children

I would like to only show posts that have "now and future" children using **pre_get_posts** action hook. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

```
function pre_get_posts($query) {        
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        //check if the query matches this post type
        if(is_post_type_archive('event')) {
            $query->set('post_parent', 0); //only show parent posts
            //should only display posts that have children from now to future
        }
    }
}
```

All events with parent_id 0 should show but it should exclude events that have no children events linked to it.

Example:

- Event 1 has 5 children. (include)
- Event 2 has no children. (exclude)
- Event 3 has 2 children. (include)
- Event 4 has 1 child. (include)
- Event 5 has no children. (exclude)

I have not yet found anything useful but will keep on looking for solutions.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: All you need to do is find the ID of your "now to future" page and substitute the `0` for that.  To find the ID, edit the page in the admin area and look in the address bar for **post=xx** - *.../wp-admin/post.php?post=50&action=edit*

Comment: My apologies. I might not have posted it clear. 

All events with parent_id of 0 should show but it should exclude the events without child events linked to it.

Comment: Do you want the children listed as well, or just the parents?

Comment: @DavidGard , i think he doesn't want to list children as he is setting `post_parent` to `0`

Comment: That's my guess too (see answer), but it's always good to check ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before amending `$query` we first have to find out which posts to exclude, which requres two querys (if I can think of a way of doing it in one I'll update the answer).

The first will grab a list of distinct ID's of all parent events, for example -

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "event" AND wp_posts.post_type = "publish" AND wp_posts.post_parent != 0
```

The next will grab the ID of all top-level events that do not have any children (so those that are not in the list we generated with the previous query), for example -

```
SELECT fgw_2_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "event" AND wp_posts.post_type = "publish" AND wp_posts.post_parent = 0 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Finally we can set the $query as required -

```
$query->set('post__not_in', $loners);
$query->set('post_parent', 0);
```

Here is the full code -

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_exclude_parents_without_children');
function my_exclude_parents_without_children($query){

    global $wpdb;

    if($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) :

        if(is_post_type_archive('event')) :

            /** First grab the ID's of all post parents */
            $my_query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT %1$s.post_parent FROM %1$s WHERE %1$s.post_type = "event" AND %1$s.post_status = "publish" AND %1$s.post_parent != 0', $wpdb->posts);
            $parents = $wpdb->get_col($my_query);

            /** Next grab the ID of all posts who do not have children (we'll call them 'loners') */
            $my_query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT %1$s.ID FROM %1$s WHERE %1$s.post_type = "event" AND %1$s.post_status = "publish" AND %1$s.post_parent = 0', $wpdb->posts, join(',', $parents));
            if(!empty($parents)) : // Ensure that there are events with children to exclude from this query
                $my_query.= $wpdb->prepare(' AND %1$s.ID NOT IN (%2$s)', $wpdb->posts, join(',', $parents));
            endif;
            $loners = $wpdb->get_col($my_query);

            /** Now exclude the 'loners' */
            $query->set('post__not_in', $loners);
            $query->set('post_parent', 0);

        endif;

    endif;

}
```

Comment: please make sure to check for admin pages ( !is_admin ) as it effects edit.php?...

Comment: @bravokeyl - Ah yes, there is a bug if I remember correctly. `is_post_type_archive()` should only work front end, but I've edited my answer to take account of this any way.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, this defect was closed as invalid because, while not typically used in the admin area, conditional tags such as `is_post_type_archive()` are expected to work - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18993.

Comment: `is_post_type_archive('wpse')` also returns true when you are in `edit.php?post_type='wpse'` .

Comment: @DavidGard That is a perfect solution for me. You are awesome. I did correct one thing though but it a minor.

WHERE %1$s.post_type = "event" AND %1$s.post_status = "publish".

Thanks again to all who helped out.

Comment: We'll spotted, I've fixed that now.